# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{ln(1-x)-sin(x)}{1-cos^2x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Applied L'Hôpital's rule, but that gives us $-2/0$ which means it has failed. What else should I do? I don't think simplifying the trigonometry will help either since we also have a $log$ term here.

Comment: @JC12 How do we ascertain that it does not exist? That is the given answer

Comment: Using the Taylors theorem gives$$\frac{\ln{(1-x)}-\sin{(x)}}{1-\cos^2{(x)}}=-\frac2x-\frac12+o(1)$$so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you want $\frac{\ln(1-x)+\sin x}{1-\cos^2x}$? Or $\frac{\ln(1+x)-\sin x}{1-\cos^2x}$?

Comment: @Angina Seng None, I wanted what I asked. Peter Foreman has already answered the question above